# Retrofit Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin, model, retrofit2

I'm new in Kotlin and I'm trying to parse a simple JSON, but I'm getting an 
`" Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter vouchers"`

`result.products` is always null, but I can see in the logs that retrofit is getting correctly the json with a 200 ok request. So I suppose that could be a problem when I'm trying to parse the json

How can I solve this?

I have add my code below

```
disposable = ApiServe.getVouchers()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result -> processVouchers(result.products) },
                { error -> error(error.message)}
            )

fun processVouchers(vouchers : List<Product>){
        mCallback?.onResponseVouchers(vouchers)
    }
```

GET VOUCHERES in ApiServe class

```
@GET(Api.ENDPOINT.VOUCHER_ENDPOIN)
        fun getVoucher(): Observable<Response<Vouchers>>
```

MODEL

```
data class Voucher(val products: List<Product>)
data class Product(val code: String, val name: String, val price: Double)
```

JSON

`{"products":[{"code":"Voucher","name":"Voucher","price":3},{"code":"Ball","name":"Voucher Ball","price":10},{"code":"Milk","name":"Voucher Milk","price":8.5}]}`

Comment: My model class in the question data class Voucher(val products: List<Product>)
data class Product(val code: String, val name: String, val price: Double)

Comment: I've generate the model class with plugin in Android Studio

Comment: This is my model class: data class Voucher(val products: List<Product>)
data class Product(val code: String, val name: String, val price: Double)

Comment: What does your getVouchers() looks like ? Have you tried to debug in the disposable when the result part is triggered (the result object) ?

Comment: yep, result objet get null on result.products Could be a problem of my model class?? I've update with getVouchers()

Comment: The getVouchers() function return a Voucher.Vouchers but your data class name is just Voucher

Comment: @S.P. ok, then what is the code of `Vouchers` class?

Comment: Not code in Voucher class. Maybe the question have to be how to do a model class in kotlin with the provided json

Comment: @S.P. just redefine `getVouchers` to: `fun getVouchers(): Observable<Voucher>`. Class `Voucher.Vouchers` is not needed (and not shown in your question)

Comment: @user2340612 I  just define the method, error disappear but I still get null in result.products

Comment: Is the JSON you posted the whole response you're getting? If that's not the case, could you please update your question with the full body? I'm asking that because if `Voucher` is an inner object then you'll need a different model

Comment: Yes is the whole json that I'm waiting

Comment: @user2340612 Yes is the whole json that I'm waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue here might be that

```
 fun getVouchers(): Observable<Voucher.Vouchers>
```

Are you sure that getVoucher returns the correct type? Shouldn't it be `Observable<Voucher>` ?

Edit:
It turned out that author was using `excludeFieldsWithModifiers` for his GsonConverterFactory, which was causing issues with parsing to model.

Comment: Yep, ok, I put fun getVouchers(): Observable<Vouche> but in my retrofit method                 { result -> processVouchers(result.products) }, products is null. But I can see in the logs that I have 200 ok and the json. I just remove from my question

Comment: are you, by any chance, using proguard?

Comment: The default proguard that is provided by Android studio. Just remove and all seem work, but I products still null. I'm quite sure that have to be a problem with model class

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other classes with name Voucher in your project that ApiService might be referring to? Quick check would be to check the imports or cmd(ctrl) + b on the return type of getVouchers

Comment: Yes, is the only one. I can change the name to another name and products = null

Comment: Great, so, where did you get this json from? Is this from logs? Are you sure that your endpoint is correct? Perhaps you could try to change getVouchers return type to ```Observable<Response<Vouchers>>``` and debug if the response is successful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193403/discussion-between-r2rek-and-s-p).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're wrapping your return type with `Response` in your `Retrofit` services interface. Just try to change like this:

```
@GET(Api.ENDPOINT.VOUCHER_ENDPOIN)
fun getVoucher(): Observable<Voucher>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong - wrapping it in Response gives you more granular control on the error checking process - without it any unsuccessful response would trigger onError. Actually wrapping it allows you to check if the error is caused by lack of internet connection or just e.g. 400 response from the server.

Comment: So why you did not wrap with a response in your answer? I'm not talking about wrapping it is useful or not. I'm just mapping the object with the given json response.

Comment: Because it is not necessary in this case, it's not causing the error though. As I said in my edited answer, the issue was in GsonConverterFactory's ```excludeFieldsWithModifiers```, which author didn't specify in his question

Comment: haha funny. I think my answer is clear and correct for mapping the given JSON. so I don't want to waste my time anymore here with you. thanks for your feedback.

Comment: it isn't, as at the beginning author had an unwrapped version, just like yours, with the same issue. go ahead and waste it wherever you please. good day